# Laravel delete directory from public

Tags: php, laravel

How could I delete a directory from the public folder? Right now I try this:

```
Storage::deleteDirectory($directory);
```

But that looks in the storage folder?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem` for this. Laravel provides the `File` facade for easy access:

```php
File::deleteDirectory(public_path('path/to/folder'));
```

The method will return `true` if it succeeds, `false` if it fails.

Comment: why its not deleting base folder ?everything inside it has been deleted but the main folder.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this:

```
 $path = 'upload/pic/foldername/';
 if (\File::exists($path)) \File::deleteDirectory($path);
```

foldername is deleting with all files in it.

Answer (score 5):

To be accessible by Storage you should define the filesystem name in `config/filesystems` and be sure to have the right permissions to be able to what you want to do.

Then something like `Storage::deleteDirectory($directory);` assuming that `$directory` is something you got properly from the corresponding resource.

Read the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem)

Answer (score 2):

You can use File instead of Storage. 
Try this one:

```
File::deleteDirectory(public_path($directory));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add first `use File;` or `use Storage;` in beginning of the file then you can use `File::deleteDirectory('path')` or `Storage::deleteDirectory('path')`

In Laravel 7,8 or above