# How can I delete the files in the temp folder I created in the public folder in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I created a folder named temp in the public directory. I need to write a function that cleans the daily temp folder. How can I delete the files in the folder?

Comment: So at the end of the day you need to delete all the files inside ```public/temp``` right ?

Comment: Storage::disk("public_path")->delete($temporary_file->your_path); you can delete file with this method

Comment: As well as the generic PHP duplicate already posted, there are also many Laravel duplicates. Please try searching before posting a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420312/laravel-delete-directory-from-public, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007356/laravel-file-storage-delete-all-files-in-directory, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41207731/deleting-a-folder-with-files-in-laravel ...

Answer (score 0):

First step an custom artisan command named ClearTemp on app/Concole/Commands/ClearTemp.php.
ClearTemp.php Content:

```
<?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

    class ClearTemp extends Command
    {
        /**
         * The name and signature of the console command.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $signature = 'clear_temp';
        /**
         * The console command description.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $description = 'Clear all file inside temp folder';
        /**
         * Create a new command instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        //
        /**
         * Execute the console command.
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle()
        {
            $this->cleanDirectory('temp');
        }
        private function cleanDirectory($path, $recursive = false)
        {
            $storage = Storage::disk('public');
            foreach ($storage->files($path, $recursive) as $file) {
                $storage->delete($file);
            }
        }
    }
```

Second step define the working frequency time of your job.In this case will be daily on app/Console/kernel.php
kernel.php content:

```
<?php
namespace App\Console;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        // EnsureQueueListenerIsRunning::class

        //
    ];
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('clear_temp')->daily();

    }
    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__ . '/Commands');
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Finally check your artisan command:

```
php artisan clear_temp
```

And make sure to activate your system cron job to check the exact time to run your function.